# Unity -- Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Tags: c#, objeto, null

Tengo problemas con este código en Unity, porqué me aparece estos errores y no se como manejarlo y necesito ayuda.

**1. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of
an object Target.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Target.cs:21).

2. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of
   an object Target.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Scripts/Target.cs:38)
   UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents: DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)**

Este es el código de **Target**:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Target: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody targetRb;
    private GameManager gameManager;
    private float minSpeed = 12;
    private float maxSpeed = 16;
    private float maxTorque = 10;
    private float xRange = 4;
    private float ySpawnPos = -6;

    public int pointValue;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        targetRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        gameManager = GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent<GameManager>();

        targetRb.AddForce(RandomForce(), ForceMode.Impulse);
        targetRb.AddTorque(RandomTorque(), RandomTorque(), RandomTorque(), ForceMode.Impulse);

        transform.position = RandomSpawnPos();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        gameManager.UpdateScore(pointValue);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    Vector3 RandomForce()
    {
        return Vector3.up * Random.Range(minSpeed, maxSpeed);
    }

    float RandomTorque()
    {
        return Random.Range(-maxTorque, maxTorque);

    }

    Vector3 RandomSpawnPos()
    {
        return new Vector3(Random.Range(-xRange, xRange), ySpawnPos);
    }
}
```

Este otro codigo es de **Game Manager**:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class GameManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> targets;
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
    private int score;
    private float spawnRate = 1.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnTarget());
        score = 0;
        UpdateScore(0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator SpawnTarget()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);
            int index = Random.Range(0, targets.Count);
            Instantiate(targets[index]);

            UpdateScore(5);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateScore(int scoreToAdd)
    {
        score += scoreToAdd;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }
}
```

El error aparece en la linea 21:

```
gameManager = GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
```

Esté error aparece en la linea 38:

```
 gameManager.UpdateScore(pointValue);
```

Si ustedes me pueden brindar ayuda se los voy agradecer. Muchas gracias.

Comment: parece que te falta colocar un `new`en la linea de GameObject y GameManager tampoco esta instanciado en ningun lugar con `new`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que encontré la solución de los problemas.

**1. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Target.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Target.cs:21).**

En la línea 21 a 25 modifiqué este código:

```
 if (gameManager != null)
    {
        gameManager = GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
    }
```

En el segundo caso que es la linea 41 **(antes 38)** a 44:

**2. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Target.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Scripts/Target.cs:38) UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents: DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)**

```
if (gameManager != null)
    {
        gameManager.UpdateScore(pointValue);
    }
```

Les incluyó el video que encontré en YouTube que me ayudo a resolver el problema.
Aquí el enlace [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGDXhUtqV0Q], se llama **How to Fix Null Reference Exception Error.**

Si alguien tiene una solución mejor, favor de escribir. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pienso que el primer problema no está ahí. El error se produce cuando intentas acceder a un miembro o una función de un objeto que no existe, es decir un null. Sería buena idea que guardes lo que te retorna GameObject.Find() en una variable y hagas la verificación sobre ella: `var temp = GameObject.Find("Game Manager");` y ahora sí el if, `if (temp != null) { gameManager = temp.GetComponent<GameManager>(); }`

Comment: Saludos @Mateo, pero no me funciono porque no es una variable temporera ,porque solo quiere encontrar el objecto Game Manager.  No hay otra manera de escribir el Script, por favor gracias.

Comment: No tiene sentido que funcione completamente bien. Con esa solución solo te deshaces de los errores. Digamos que por defecto tienes que `gameManager = null`. Luego estás diciendo que solo si `gameManager != null` le vas a asignar una instancia. Lo que consigues es que `gameManager` nunca esté asignado a menos que lo hagas desde el editor y que nunca se llame a `UpdateScore()`

Answer (score 0):

El código está correcto, el problema fue es que escribí el código
**incorrecto:**
gameManager = GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent();

El código **correcto es:**
gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent();

Es importante mirar que el nombre este correcto en el **Inspector** en **Unity** subrayado en rojo, ya que produjo dicho error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]